# Make changes to PHP script to run as Perl script

Tags: php, perl

I have a PHP script for seperating the header and text of an email. I wanted to convert it to a Perl script such that it will take the email as input file from the user.
The following is the PHP script:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php  
//debug  
#ini_set ("display_errors", "1");  
#error_reporting(E_ALL);  

//include email parser  
require_once('/path/to/class/rfc822_addresses.php');  
require_once('/path/to/class/mime_parser.php');  

// read email in from stdin  
$fd = fopen(ARGV[0], "r");  
$email = "";  
while (!feof($fd)) {  
    $email .= fread($fd, 1024);  
}  
fclose($fd);  

//create the email parser class  
$mime=new mime_parser_class;  
$mime->ignore_syntax_errors = 1;  
$parameters=array(  
    'Data'=>$email,  
);  

$mime->Decode($parameters, $decoded);  

//---------------------- GET EMAIL HEADER INFO -----------------------//  

//get the name and email of the sender  
$fromName = $decoded[0]['ExtractedAddresses']['from:'][0]['name'];  
$fromEmail = $decoded[0]['ExtractedAddresses']['from:'][0]['address'];  

//get the name and email of the recipient  
$toEmail = $decoded[0]['ExtractedAddresses']['to:'][0]['address'];  
$toName = $decoded[0]['ExtractedAddresses']['to:'][0]['name'];  

//get the subject  
$subject = $decoded[0]['Headers']['subject:'];  

$removeChars = array('<','>');  

//get the message id  
$messageID = str_replace($removeChars,'',$decoded[0]['Headers']['message-id:']);  

//get the reply id  
$replyToID = str_replace($removeChars,'',$decoded[0]['Headers']['in-reply-to:']);  

//---------------------- FIND THE BODY -----------------------//  

//get the message body  
if(substr($decoded[0]['Headers']['content-type:'],0,strlen('text/plain')) == 'text/plain' && isset($decoded[0]['Body'])){  

    $body = $decoded[0]['Body'];  

} elseif(substr($decoded[0]['Parts'][0]['Headers']['content-type:'],0,strlen('text/plain')) == 'text/plain' && isset($decoded[0]['Parts'][0]['Body'])) {  

    $body = $decoded[0]['Parts'][0]['Body'];  

} elseif(substr($decoded[0]['Parts'][0]['Parts'][0]['Headers']['content-type:'],0,strlen('text/plain')) == 'text/plain' && isset($decoded[0]['Parts'][0]['Parts'][0]['Body'])) {  

    $body = $decoded[0]['Parts'][0]['Parts'][0]['Body'];  

}  

//print out our data  
echo " 

Message ID: $messageID 

Reply ID: $replyToID 

Subject: $subject 

To: $toName $toEmail 

From: $fromName $fromEmail 

Body: $body 

";  

//show all the decoded email info  
print_r($decoded);
```

I just needed to know what changes should i make to make it run as a Perl script?

Comment: If you want it to run nativly in Perl, you would have to reqrite it in perl!

Comment: You need to change almost everything after the first # since perl and php are different languages.

Comment: http://p3rl.org/Courriel parses MIME messages.

Answer (score 10):

For almost anything dealing with email and Perl, you probably want [Email::Simple](https://www.metacpan.org/module/Email%3a%3aSimple). I think this is close to what that PHP script does (although there must be a better way to do it in PHP). Once you create the Email::Simple object, you just ask for the parts you want without thinking about how it extracts them:

```
use Email::Simple;

my $text = ...;
my $email = Email::Simple->new( $text );

my( $body ) = $email->body;
my( $messageID, $replyToID, $subject, $to, $from ) = 
        map { scalar $email->header($_) || undef } qw(
            message-id
            reply-to
            subject
            to
            from
            );


print <<"HERE";
Message ID: $messageID 
Reply ID: $replyToID 
Subject: $subject 
To: $to 
From: $from

Body: $body
HERE
```

For the MIME parts, there's also [Email::MIME](https://www.metacpan.org/module/Email%3a%3aMIME). You should be able to figure out it from the example in the documentation. I don't know why you'd why to print it though, considering it might be images, movies, binary PDFs, and other things that would screw up your terminal.

Good luck, :)